# NetBeans, html5 project. What is the difference between Site Root Folder and Source Folder?

Tags: netbeans, frontend, netbeans-8.1

Always I store an all my front-end sources in Site Root Folder.
But today I update netbeans to 8.1 and I notice the Source Folder in the project properties.
What this folder for?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is good explained in NetBeans Help -> Project Properties Window: Sources

**Site Root Folder**
The contents of this folder will be available through the web server on the production site. It contains the HTML, CSS and JS files that are publicly accessible/visible. This folder typically contains the index.html file.

**Source Folder**
The folder in the project that serves for server-side sources (typically node.js JS files). If the project is a JS library, JavaScript files should be placed in this folder (not in the Site Root Folder).

Answer (score 0):

When you use Grunt or Gulp you should store sources and final site and different folders.